# How to update directive when a scope variable changes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive that highlights text in a div if it contains a one of the specific keywords: Like below

```js
    angular.module('app', []).directive('words', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var words = element.attr('words').split(' ');
          
          for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
            var r = new RegExp(words[i], 'ig')
            element.html(element.html().replace(r, '<span class="highlight">' + words[i] + '</span>'));
          }
        }
      };
    })
```

```css
  .highlight {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    
    <div ng-app="app" words="automobile physiology crime">
     The dentist travels every coverage.
     The talent pumps opposite the automobile. 
     The poet shies away under a frightening day.
     The innovative physiology breezes above the ideology.
     A manned waste fusses next to the hardback crime.
     The changing conflict recovers in my fewer sermon.
     </div>
```

However, the keywords and the content of the div is updated because they contains `scope` variables. In this case, the text is not highlighted. How can I update the directive on scope variable change?

This is my real code

```
<div ng-app="app" words="{{search.keywords}}">{{search.results}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove the interpolation:

```
<!--REMOVE interpolation
<div ng-app="app" words="{{search.keywords}}">{{search.results}}</div>
-->

<div ng-app="app" words="search.keywords">{{search.results}}</div>
```

Then use a watcher:

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('words', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.$watch(attrs.words, function(newValue) {
          if (!newValue) return;

          var words = newValue.split(' ');

          for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
            var r = new RegExp(words[i], 'ig')
            element.html(element.html().replace(r, '<span class="highlight">' + words[i] + '</span>'));
          };
       });
    }

  };
})
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference - $watch.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    words: '='
  }
}
```

in your directive to make two way bindings

And change this

```
<div ng-app="app" words="{{search.keywords}}">{{search.results}}</div>
```

to

```
<div ng-app="app" words="search.keywords">{{search.results}}</div>
```

And also change this part

```
var words = element.attr('words').split(' ');
```

to

```
var words = scope.words.split(' ');
```